# Обработка форм Node.js

Tags: node.js, веб-программирование, post, form, веб-сервер

Есть сайт - [сайт](https://artemdzukaev.000webhostapp.com/pages/contacts.html). У него есть форма, которая передает данные через метод POST.

Как с помощью Node.js, получить данные(желательно, чтобы name и email были в отдельных переменных)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По моему вам нужен BodyParser 
[Ссылка](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser)